# How do you get the network interface index for the loopback interface?

Tags: c++, c, networking, posix

I'm writing an app that needs to bind to the loopback interface by interface index. The lazy way to do this would just be to use interface index 1, or even use `if_nametoindex("lo0")`.

However, is that technically correct? Is `lo0` guaranteed to exist, and be the network interface with index 1? If so, that answers my question, but if not, what's the correct way to get the loopback interface's index?

(Note: This is in regards to Unix-like environments like macOS or Linux, not Windows.)

Comment: No, all assumptions are invalid.

Comment: Mine is usually called `lo`. Also you can have more than one, or none (which usually breaks programs) and they can have IP addresses other than 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @user253751 That's what I thought. I've at least heard of people having more than one loopback interface. I wasn't sure if you could have zero. That being the case, I wonder what the correct way to find its interface index is?

Comment: You can even have one called `fred`. You could use rtnetlink to get all interfaces and look for one with IFF_LOOPBACK flag, but rtnetlink is non-trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that loopback interfaces can be added and removed, I wrote a function to find the first one and return its index. It returns 0 if there are no loopback interfaces (or it fails to get information about the available interfaces).

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include <net/if_types.h>

uint32_t loopbackInterfaceIndex()
{
    uint32_t result = 0;
    ifaddrs *interfaces;
    
    if (getifaddrs(&interfaces) == -1) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    for(ifaddrs *interface = interfaces; interface; interface = interface->ifa_next) {
        if (interface->ifa_addr && interface->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK) {
            sockaddr_dl *addr = (sockaddr_dl *)interface->ifa_addr;
            
            if (addr->sdl_type == IFT_LOOP) {
                result = if_nametoindex(interface->ifa_name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    
    return result;
}
```